# What is advantage of using will-change property instead of translate3d for hardware acceleration?

Tags: javascript, css

In the interesting article [Everything You Need to Know About the CSS will-change Property](https://dev.opera.com/articles/css-will-change-property/) it says that using the `translate3d()` hack is the old way of doing things if you want hardware acceleration, and instead of that you should use `will-change`. Is there any benefit in performance when using `will-change`? I have found it is extremely difficult in some cases to add `will-change` via JavaScript just before element triggers animation. For example

1. You can't just put `will-change` in CSS and expect it to work, because it will be worse if you had multiple elements.
2. You can't either put `will-change` in `:hover` pseudo selector because the browser needs some time to prepare.
3. You are left with animation on click event, when you can add `willChange` on hover via JavaScript leaving the browser enough time to prepare (200ms).

Overall you must somehow predict users behavior and that is difficult. It is too complicated (you must, also, remove `will-change` after animation ends) over `translate3d()`. Why use it?

Comment: Checkout those 2 articles to get more details:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/will-change
https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/w/will-change/

Comment: I have read all those articles before posting question. Check my linked article for clarification of my question.

Comment: @JeremyBanks I have updated post, hope it helps!

Comment: @dasdsdsdsa Thanks! I wasn't aware of `will-change`. Interesting to read about...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. As you've already stated, specifying a transform constitutes a hack. `will-change` is a standard.
2. There are guidelines around when to use `will-change` and when not to (with the general idea of using it sparingly and only when you need to). On the other hand, many authors recommend using the transform hack without abandon.

If you expect a user to interact with an element in a way that triggers some resource-intensive visual effect, set `will-change`. Simple as that. You don't have to predict when or if the user will ever interact with the element and decide whether or not to set `will-change` — you just set `will-change` and let the browser worry about the rest.

You don't `will-change` *all* the things, but the moment you expect a certain property to change on a certain element, tell the browser that that specific property `will-change` on that specific element. Whether or not a user actually triggers the change in that specific page load or browsing session is irrelevant to you as the author.

`will-change` doesn't inherently have better performance — in fact, it does pretty much the same thing as the transform hack at a high level. The performance boost comes mostly from judicious use of `will-change` so you don't waste system resources on things that don't need them (see point #2 above).

Comment: As I understood the author of the posted link, she means one should add `will-change` if it's likely that a change will happen and remove it afterwards.
Which adds another layer of complexity, you have to think what should trigger the `will-change` attribute to be added and will there be enough time for the browser to make the optimizations before the animation actually gets triggered.

Btw. What is the `transform hack without abandon`? Is this hack still an option?

Comment: @Legends: The "transform hack" is the translate3d() hack mentioned in the question. "without abandon" is merely an English expression meaning "indiscriminately and excessively", it's not a CSS term.